# How to undo command in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gcc

Command:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt install gcc-9 g++-9
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 90 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-9
```

Now my gcc version is 9.5 (11 was before)

How i can delete these update-alternative and give back my gcc 11??

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to manually removing packages and the PPA, there's a more automated way of doing it with `ppa-purge`. In your case you'd run:

`sudo ppa-purge -o ubuntu-toolchain -p test`

The following format also works

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

From the documentation:

```
ppa-purge will reset all packages from a PPA to the standard
versions released for your distribution.
```